# OpenLDAP CLI Authentication failed

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

I have a OpenLDAP Server running on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.
I also installed PhpLDAPAdmin, the PHPLdapAdmin works fine and I can authenticate.
Also if I run for example at the CLI ldapsearch it works fine.
But as soon as I try to run a CLI Function where authentication is required I get always a authentication failed:

```
ubuntu@LDAP-machne:~$ ldapwhoami -H ldap://localhost -w PWD
   SASL/DIGEST-MD5 authentication started
   ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49)
```

In the PHPLdapAdmin if I check my password it works, do I have to make a additional command or explicit encoding?
The Encoding is ssha.

If run the same command as openldap user it works. 
But per default I should be able to run ldap commands also as root.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ldapwhoami` tries to connect using an SASL authorization identity, your command is the same as :

`ldapwhoami -H ldap://localhost -w PWD -X u:<login>`. If you have not in your directory users to match this authentication request it will not work.

Try : `ldapwhoami -H ldap://localhost -w PWD -x -D <dn of the entry with password "PWD">`